# traefik access backend service through ip

Tags: grpc

Because I don't have a domain name, I want to use IP to directly access the /ping method in the backend service running in docker. How do I configure it?

```
    Here is the code part:
    
     func main() {
        r := gin.Default()
        r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
                "message": "pong",
            })
        })
        r.Run(":3002")
    }
                                                                                                                                                            
    
    Here is the docker-compose configuration:
    
    version: '3.3'
    
    services:
      main:
        container_name: main
        image: hello:latest
        working_dir: /hello
        ports:
          - "3002:3002"
        restart: always
        labels:
          - "traefik.frontend.main.rule=PathPrefixStrip: /hello"
        network_mode: traefik
```

correct format：

```
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.hello.service=hello"
      - "traefik.http.routers.hello.rule=Host(`192.168.000.001`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.hello.loadbalancer.server.port=3002"
```

Comment: Please ask [one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735). 1 - That is possible; what specific issue are you facing? 2 - You could put Traefik in front of gRPC-Gateway but I don't believe it has the functionality to replace it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and reply, I have refined and revised the question

Comment: If you are using traefik then you will need to include it's config ([minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With what you have shown I'd assume a GET to http://127.0.0.1:3002/ping` from the host machine will return the pong. If so the next step will be to make this available via your public IP (and how you do that will depend upon your setup; i.e. local firewall, does the computer have a public IP (in which case it may already be accessible) or is it behind NAT (which most machines will be). You would need to provide a lot more info.

Comment: I have added the configuration information for the traefik container, sorry I can't publish my public ip address

Comment: Your external IP is not needed but what is needed is information on how it's configured and what you have tried (i.e. can you access this locally). `network_mode: traefik` [does not look valid](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode) to me and I don't believe these containers will share a network? You still have two questions here (configuring traefik and access via external IP); pick one (so maybe get your app running and accessible without traefik first, then put everything in one `docker-compose.yml` and get that working before adding more complexity).

Comment: I'm sorry to reply to you for such a long time. I have solved this problem. Maybe I had the wrong way before. I just need to change the value in the host to the IP